# MultiHeadAttention masking with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, masking, transformer-model, self-attention

I have been trying to make a custom mask for targetted combinations of queries and keys for my MultiHeadAttention layer but can not figure out the way to use this layer masking.

Here is an example with a dummy dataset (batch size 1) :

```
key     = tf.ones([1, 32 , 128])
mask    = tf.concat([
    tf.concat([tf.zeros([16 , 16]) , tf.zeros([16 , 16]) ] , 0) ,
    tf.concat([tf.zeros([16 , 16]) , tf.ones([16 , 16])  ] , 0) ] , 1)
mask    = mask[tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, : , : ]


# key shape  -> ( 1 , 32 , 128 )
# mask shape -> ( 1 , 1,  32 , 32 )
```

when I print `mask[0][0].numpy()` I get :

[image: masking]

Now using the foolowing layer ( 1 head , self-attention ) :

```
mha_layer =  tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention( num_heads=1, key_dim=128 )
attention_output, attention_scores = mha_layer(  key , key , attention_mask=mask  ,  return_attention_scores=True)
```

I get the folowing attention scores (`attention_scores[0][0].numpy()`) :

[image: attention scores]

Here the dark-violet color stands for 0.0 , yellow for 0.06 and green-blue for 0.03

I would expect to have expected the green-blue part to be 0.0s because of the masking.

Am I using the masking wrong ? or it is not possible to mask entire queries/keys ?

I hope my question makes sense  and that it is not too obvious.
Thank you in advance, if you can help :)